# simplest http server that supports SSI?

Tags: ssi, httpserver

I am developing a web prototype, but I need to reuse HTML code.
I couldn't find any client solutions to include html files and now I'm trying to find a simple http server that requires no configuration like for example: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` and supports SSI.

Comment: Have you looked at django's web server? the reused Html code could be served as your template

Comment: django is an option but I was willing to find something easier to setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the new PHP 5.4 adds a simple server and its [very easy to setup and run](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php): `php -S localhost:8000`.
Then I can easily reuse HTML code using the include PHP function:
`<?php include("common/top-logged-bar.html"); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/valenok/mongoose

mongoose web server might help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: this is the source code link and user may ask where to get , that's why giving download link also